# solving mixed integer program with LINGO

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-functions, lingo

i need to solve the below problem in LINGO.
[image]

i declared the sets and data but there is an error in constraint one. i think my syntax is wrong. anybody can help me writing the right constraints.
my syntax in LINGO:
the error i got in constraint 1 is :

> too many inequality or equality relations

```
MODEL:
SETS:
    prefer_list: MU , W;
    products : num;
    Index;
    X(index,index);

ENDSETS
DATA:
    prefer_list, MU = MU1..MU8;
    MU = 2.32   7.14    2.32    8.3     7.14    7.14    1.17    2.32;
    num = 5;
    index=1..5;
ENDDATA

    !objectives;
    Max = @SUM(prefer_list(i):MU(i) * W(i));
    !constraints;
    @for(X(i,j)| j #LT# i:  @BIN(X(j,i))+ X(i,j)=1 );


END
```